# Spring Boot - how to retrieve selected item on drop down?

Tags: database, spring, drop-down-menu, spring-boot

I'm facing the following problem in the User edit screen:

Imagine the following classes User and Country,
and I have a table for each one and the relationship is one to many.

That way in the session of edit screen we have in which country the user is registered and display a
drop down to update this information,
but I'd like to bring selected the current user's country and other countries, how can I do?

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="country">Country</label>

 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <select id="country" th:field="*{user.name}" class="form-control"
    required="required">
   <option value="">Select...</option>
   <option th:each="c : ${countries}" th:value="${c.id}"
     th:text="${c.name}" value=""></option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Thymeleaf and Springboot.

---

#### Solved

For the code to work, just change this way:

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="country">Country</label>

 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <select id="country" name="user.country" class="form-control"
    required="required">
   <option value="">Select...</option>
   <option th:each="c : ${countries}" th:value="${c.id}"
     th:text="${c.name}" th:selected="(${c.id} == *{user.country.id})"></option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

I found the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206849/spring-mvc-thymeleaf-thselected-not-working):

"according to the thymeleaf forum ([post](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-selected-not-working-on-multiple-select-tp4025883p4025884.html)) th:field doesn't work with th:selected"

Comment: Well, that depends which technology you use for your UI. Since you haven't given this information, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @jHilscher: That is the code that I wanna change: 
`<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="country">Country</label>

 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <select id="country" th:field="*{user.name}" class="form-control"
    required="required">
   <option value="">Select...</option>
   <option th:each="c : ${countries}" th:value="${c.id}"
     th:text="${c.name}" value=""></option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>`

@dunni: I'm using Thymeleaf and Springboot.

Comment: Please move your solution to your own answer, thank you.