# thymeleaf replacing th:field to comply with th:selected

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I appreciate your passing by my post. I have searched here in StackOverFlow and google as well to fix my following code:

**My HTML code:**

```
<form th:action="@{/surgerywaitinglist/saveToWaitinList}"
            th:object="${waitinglistDTO}" method="POST">
.
.
.    
<select name="departmentName"
                                        
            th:field="*{department.departmentName}"
            th:with="departmentName = ${waitinglistDTO.department.departmentName}"
            class="form-control" id="departmentJS">
        
        <option value="" th:selected="selected" 
              th:disabled="disabled">select option
        </option>
                                                
        <option th:each="department: ${departments}"
                th:value="${department.departmentName}"
                th:text="${department.departmentName}"> 
        </option>
        
    </select>
.
.
.
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

form other posts like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206849/spring-mvc-thymeleaf-thselected-not-working) I found out that th:field and th:selected do not work together; in fact, th:field needs to be replace with something else. Notice that the th:object holds another object (from Department class) ...

**My DTO class:**

```
public class WaitinglistDTO {

    private Long waitingListId;
    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter a procedure")
    private String waitingListProcedure;
    private String waitingListDiagnosis;
    private Long waitingListPatientId;
    private Long waitingListSurgeonId;
    private Long waitingListDepartmentId;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
    private Date waitingListAdditionDate;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE)
    private Date waitingListActualBookingDate;
    
    
    private Patient patient;
    private Surgeon surgeon;
    private Department department;
```

***Could you help me figure this out?***

Many thanxxxxx :)

...
**Update:**

The following image explains how it should look,,, however, the default option should be the **select option** which should be somehow **disabled**
[image]

This is the result I get when I apply the suggested code of [Rafael da Silva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14133911/rafael-da-silva) ,, you can see the pre-selected option is the first option rather than the **select option** option :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would add the selected to the blank option, the first option is always selected if your model object has nothing set and if it does normal behaviour would be to have that item selected, which `th:field` should resolve.

In case you want the select to always start at the default option, even if the model has another value or want to set it some other way. you can set `th:id="*{department.departmentName}"` and `th:name="*{department.departmentName}"` and than manualy handle `th:selected`.

As a side note theres no need to use the `th` version `th:selected="selected"` if using static values just `selected` or `selected="selected` would sufice in that case

Edit with code, not tested as i don't have my work pc where i am.

If you want to always have the first option selected even when editing with previous data

```html
<select name="departmentName" th:name="*{department.departmentName}" th:id="*{department.departmentName}" class="form-control" id="departmentJS">
    <option selected disabled>select option</option>
    <option th:each="department : ${departments}" th:value="${department.departmentName}" th:text="${department.departmentName}"></option>
</select>
```

If you want to fill with existing data but default to the first option

```html
<select name="departmentName" th:field="*{department.departmentName}"  class="form-control" id="departmentJS">
    <option disabled>select option</option>
    <option th:each="department : ${departments}" th:value="${department.departmentName}" th:text="${department.departmentName}"></option>
</select>
```

I'm not 100% sure on the use of disabled but i think it should work, personally i would just leave it selectable and enforce a @notnull on your bean in controller validation.
the `th:with` annotation does nothing asfar i can see, what `th:with` is used for is defining a new variable for all elements nested inside the elment you define it on. example:

```html
<div th:with="newVar='someString'">
    <span th:text="${newVar}"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank Ralan,, would you please make the changes on the whole code.... I am new to thymeleaf ....

Comment: For your first comment, the need for an blank option is essential since first the drop down list selected option (that is Department) will be captured by a JS code to call for the second drop down list (that is Surgeon)..... If you have a different approach to match the target end,,, I am all ears ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
<select name="departmentName" th:field="*{department.departmentName}" th:with="departmentName = ${waitinglistDTO.department.departmentName}" class="form-control" id="departmentJS">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">select option</option>
    <option th:each="department : ${departments}" th:value="${department.departmentName}" th:text="${department.departmentName}"></option>
</select>
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too :)
But this not what I was looking for!

I needed to use th:selected or something else. Your code only omitted the option with th:selected with no suggestion or solution :)

Now, when the select portion is populated I get the first option selected for the user!
What I needed is to set the first option to a message for the user to choose an option as a default option rather that setting an actual option!
I hope you get my idea :)

Tnanx for your time.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think this solves your problem.

Comment: thank you for the effort,,, but this leads to the same original problem :) you can see the image I posted above

Comment: this should work except since the object  (th:object="${waitinglistDTO}") is  inside the <form> something holding it back !